# Not able to use >= to compare user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to code a program that when the user inputs his numerical grade, the system will give the user his letter grade. This is my code so far (would copy and paste for A,A-,B+, etc)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterGrade
{
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char grade;

            System.out.println("Enter your grade in numeric form ");

            if (userInput >= 97 && grade <= 100)
            {grade = "A+";}
            System.out.println("Your letter grade is " + grade);
    }
}
```

The error messages that I'm getting are:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Lab2>javac LetterGrade.java
LetterGrade.java:14: operator >= cannot be applied to java.util.Scanner,int
                        if (userInput >= 97 && grade <= 100)
                                      ^
LetterGrade.java:15: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: char
                        {grade = "A+";}
                                 ^
2 errors
```

I've used java for less than one week, and I don't know where the problem is.

Edit: Found the problem with the "A+". changed from char grade; -> string grade;.

Comment: You are trying to use `>=` on a `Scanner` object. Are you meaning to use it on `grade`, a `char`? Also, if you need to store more than one character of data, such as `A+`, you will need to use `String`.

Comment: The error message is -- correctly -- telling you that the left-hand side is a `Scanner`, not an `int`. For a numeric comparison, both sides need to be numbers.

Comment: Note: If you used an IDE, these errors would be seen before you tried to compile and run the code yourself

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm sure he will get there in time. An IDE can often be too much for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to comapre an `int` to a `Scanner` object. This doesn't make much sense. I think you wanted to try to compare what the user enters. You can use the [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method to read the numeric value of the grade. Something like:

```
String letterGrade = "";
int grade = userInput.nextInt();
if(grade >= 97 && grade <= 100) {
   letterGrade = "A+";
}
```

(Note that `letterGrade` must be a `String` not a `char` as it needs to be two characters)

Comment: @KenY-N As a side note, you cannot use array brackets on `String`. You would need to use `charAt()`.

Comment: @Ken It appears OP is trying to enter numbers, not characters